# Prove the value of this infinite series

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose that $\{a_n\}$, $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence such that
$a_{2n} \to \alpha$ and $a_{2n+1} \to \beta$.
Prove that
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1}{n} \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{j}{j+1} a_j = \frac{\alpha+\beta}{2}$$
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}\frac{j}{j+1}a_j=\frac{1}{n} \left ( \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor }\frac{2k}{2k+1}a_{2k}+ \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor }\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}a_{2k+1}\right ) $$

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $\alpha_k:=\frac{2k}{2k+1}a_{2k}\rightarrow \alpha$ and $\beta_k:=\frac{2k+1}{2k+2}a_{2k+1}\rightarrow\beta$. You have by Cesaro limit theorem:

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}\alpha_k}{[n/2]}\rightarrow \alpha,$$

so

$$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^{[n/2]}\alpha_k}{n}\rightarrow \alpha/2.$$

A similar result follows for $\beta_n$. Can you put it together now to complete the proof?